# How can I select the last list item of a specific class in a list of items?

Tags: css

```
<ul>
    <li class="special"></li>
    <li class="special"></li>
    <li class="special"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

In this example I would like to target only the last `.special` list item. Is this possible using only CSS?

Comment: You cannot, with only CSS

Comment: @Mr.Alien Thank you for answering. I don't understand why my question was downvoted and marked as a possible duplicate when it is it not. I get whoever marked it as such didn't even read it.

Comment: @bernk I hardly hardly downvote, but it is duplicate, so it is marked as duplicate :)

Comment: It's a duplicate, but it's not a duplicate of *using last-child*.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve it by using pure CSS.

I'd suggest alternative way by using javascript, or more specific `jQuery` by utilizing **[:last selector](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/)**:

```
$('ul li.special:last').css('color','red');
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yrKhL/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Using css alone, check this out. [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9LPtd/)

```
li:nth-child(3){
color:#f00;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this only works if the list is static. In my case it is not.

Comment: In that case, Felix's solution can help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps if you target the first non-special element like this:

```
ul .special + li:not(.special) { background: red; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know it's always three items you could do something like this

```
.special + .special + .special {
    // your styles
}
```