# Applying CSS styles only to the lowest instance of a class

Tags: css, sass

I'm putting together some CSS/SASS for menu from html that has been supplied to me. When I'm on a page about Red Apples, the html looks something like this:

```
<ul class="navigation">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Fruit</a>
        <ul>
            <li>Banana
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Yellow</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Green</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Apple</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Green</a></li>
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Red</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Yellow</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Vegetables</a></li>
</ul>
```

When I'm on a page about Apples, there is no `active` class on the colours, so that portion might look like this:

```
<li class="active"><a href="#">Apple</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Green</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Red</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Yellow</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Likewise, if I'm on a page about fruit, the Apples list item will lose its `active` class.

My question is, given this markup, is there a way using just CSS/SASS to apply a background colour **only** the lowest instance of the `active` class?

Edit: [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aWRPZ/3/)

Comment: can you please fiddle it?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45004/complex-css-selector-for-parent-of-active-child

Comment: @Zoe, take a look at these posts 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22148594/how-can-i-select-the-last-list-item-of-a-specific-class-in-a-list-of-items?lq=1, 2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13211453/css-how-to-say-classlast-of-type-classes-not-elements, 3. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401268/how-do-i-select-the-last-child-with-a-specific-class-name-in-css?lq=1 However, I don't know of any method of achieving what you are after with *pure CSS* only. You have to use `Javascript` or `jQuery` or any other library based on `Javascript` for this particular task.

Comment: Thanks Pumbaa80 and @W.D. I was 99.9% certain the lack of a parent selector would make this impossible with css alone, but was just holding a glimmer of hope that maybe there was some sass trickery to get around that limitation, maybe with `@if` or similar. Doesn't look hopeful!

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `Javascript` for this task?

Comment: Just the general desire to limit js wherever possible. Instead of js, I'll probably go back to the xslt guy and plead for an extra selector to hook into :)

Comment: Well it's up to you and good luck ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS does not support any parent selectors. You will have to use JQuery to achieve your requirement.

For example you can write the below code to make yours work

In Css give

```
li.active{ color: "#ff0000";}
```

In Jquery

```
$(".active").has(".active").css("color","#000000");
```

This will make all elements with class active to have text color as red and once that have another element with class active to have text color black

Comment: Since there doesn't appear to be a purely css solution to my problem, I'll mark this work-around as the correct answer. Thanks for your help!